# Mix of categorical and continuous data in neural network

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks

Given a shallow or deep neural network, how would one go about using both continuous numerical input features and categorical features?

For example, given a network that receives a set of 100 continuous numerical values between 0 and 1 representing monetary value, how would I also include a time component? I would suspect one would have to discretize/translate intraday hours and minutes, e.g. 21:35 into bins of say 1 hour. This would yield a one-hot vector that I would then append to my input data that flows into the network. Would this be a valid approach?

Comment: What is your definition of a neural network? As far as I remember, the input does not have to be categorial, you can also have neurons accepting continuous data.

Answer (score 1):

Barring exotic cases, NNs operate on floats. Period. Big floats, small floats, 16/32/64 bit floats - but floats all the same. So yes, you do have to encode your data somehow to floats - how you do that will depend on what you're trying to do.

Now, for time, you may have two use-cases I can think of.

First is that you're trying to account for the time of day itself, but don't care for higher-level trends (day on day, week on week,  etc., you're assuming they stay the same).

In this case, you can actually get a perfectly continuous encoding just by encoding to some periodic function, like a sine where you set 0.5 as noon, or whatever.

Second is that you're doing time series. In this case you want to have a sliding window over all time periods, which is exactly what 1D Convolutions give you if the D in question is time.

Answer (score 1):

For datetime components, best trick is cyclical encoding. This lets the model learn that 1am and 11pm are similar (which isn't the case if you were to feed it raw variables of 01 and 23).
Example code for month, or week of year:

```
df['checkin_month_sin'] = np.sin((df["checkin_month"]-1)*(2.*np.pi/12))
df['checkin_month_cos'] = np.cos((df["checkin_month"]-1)*(2.*np.pi/12))

df['checkin_week_sin'] = np.sin((df["checkin_week"]-1)*(2.*np.pi/53))
df['checkin_week_cos'] = np.cos((df["checkin_week"]-1)*(2.*np.pi/53))
```

Here's a code example notebook: https://www.kaggle.com/danofer/datetime-embeddings-for-end-to-end-deep-learning
And I give some more examples in a presentation I made, (lazily linking): https://github.com/ddofer/talk/blob/master/Introduction%20to%20Time%20Series%20and%20Feature%20Engineering.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I refer the book Introduction to Machine Learning with Python (Müller and Guido) *translated from French*:
"The neural networks are expecting all features to vary/change in a similar way, ideally a mean of 0 and a variance of 1". So I do not think to use a discretisation is a good idea, so to avoid bins feature or one-hot encoding is wise I guess.